# After finishing an activity and going back to a prev activity, how do I use variables from the finished activity (w/o StartActivity)?

Tags: android

So I have one activity, InputScores, (that was called from a parent activity, Scoreboard) where the user inputs values, and clicks a button so that those *values will be saved in the Scoreboard activity*, where some math will be done via a procedure.

Since I am returning to a previous activity that's already loaded, **I cannot use startActivity()** as that will just lead to pressing the back button 40 times to quit the application. So, what would I use instead, if not `finish()` nor `finishActivity()`? Instead of intent.putExtra(), what commands would I use to pass some integer variables to the Scoreboard activity?

Additionally, on the Scoreboard activity, how would I make it so that a subroutine that *takes input from the finished activity* only works after that button was pressed? And how would I recall aforementioned integers without intents?

The code for the button in InputScores.

```
// The button
Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit_scores);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Retreive values from EditTexts
        ...
        int addend1;
        int addend2;
        int addend3;
        int addend4;
        int addend5;
        ...

        // Computes sum for this checksum
        int sumForChecksum = addend1 + addend2 + addend3 + addend4 + addend5;
        ...
        if (!checksum) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence checksumFail = getString(R.string.checksum_fail);
            int toastDuration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast ChecksumFail = Toast.makeText(context, checksumFail, toastDuration);
            ChecksumFail.show();
        } else {
            // Convert these to scores
            // Sets modifiers
            int modifier = 1;
            if (currentRoundInteger >= 7) {
                modifier *= -1;
            }
            if (promptElement % 2 == 0) {
                modifier *= 2;
            } else if (promptElement == 1) {
                modifier *= 8;
            } else if (promptElement == 3) {
                modifier *= 4;
            } else {
                modifier *= 16;
            }
            System.out.print(modifier);
            // What I need to do is put the values of addend1 through addend 5 AND modifier into Scoreboard.java. BUT I cannot startactivity
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(InputScores.this, Scoreboard.class);
            intent1.putExtra("modifier", modifier);

            intent1.putExtra("player 1 change", addend1);
            intent1.putExtra("player 2 change", addend2);
            intent1.putExtra("player 3 change", addend3);
            intent1.putExtra("player 4 change", addend4);
            intent1.putExtra("player 5 change", addend5);

            int modifierBit = Math.round(Math.round(Math.log(Math.abs(modifier)) / Math.log(2)));
            // addend1, addend2, addend3, addend4, addend5 (+1 to each to maintain numeric place), modifier + or -, log base 2 of modifier
            // If there's a better way to manage a dynamic token, I'll gladly replace this with that.
            int mathToken = 1000000 * (1 + addend1) + 100000 * (1 + addend2) + 10000 * (1 + addend3) + 1000 * (1 + addend4) + 100 * (1 + addend5) + modifierBit;
            // Positive round modifiers = 1 in the tens place in the token
            if (modifier > 0) {
                mathToken += 10;
            }
            intent1.putExtra("math token", mathToken);
            finishActivity(255);
        }
    }
});
```

The code for Scoreboard

```
advance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Scoreboard.this, InputScores.class);
        int requestCode = 255;
        // Just code that would go into InputScores that would have already executed
        ...
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int mInt = intent2.getIntExtra("math token", 0);
    TextView player1scores = findViewById(R.id.player1scores);
    player1scores.setText(mInt);
    // code goes here
    int i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

*Scoreboard.java*

Remove this code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int mInt = intent2.getIntExtra("math token", 0);
    TextView player1scores = findViewById(R.id.player1scores);
    player1scores.setText(mInt);
    // code goes here
    int i = 0;
}
```

Add this code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 255) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int mInt = data.getIntExtra("math token", 0);
            TextView player1scores = findViewById(R.id.player1scores);
            player1scores.setText(mInt);
            // code goes here
            int i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

*InputScores.java*

```
// What I need to do is put the values of addend1 through addend 5 
// AND modifier into Scoreboard.java. BUT I cannot startactivity
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent1.putExtra("modifier", modifier);

intent1.putExtra("player 1 change", addend1);
intent1.putExtra("player 2 change", addend2);
intent1.putExtra("player 3 change", addend3);
intent1.putExtra("player 4 change", addend4);
intent1.putExtra("player 5 change", addend5);

int modifierBit = Math.round(Math.round(Math.log(Math.abs(modifier)) / Math.log(2)));
// addend1, addend2, addend3, addend4, addend5 (+1 to each to maintain numeric place), modifier + or -, log base 2 of modifier
// If there's a better way to manage a dynamic token, I'll gladly replace this with that.
int mathToken = 1000000 * (1 + addend1) + 100000 * (1 + addend2) + 10000 * (1 + addend3) + 1000 * (1 + addend4) + 100 * (1 + addend5) + modifierBit;
// Positive round modifiers = 1 in the tens place in the token
if (modifier > 0) {
    mathToken += 10;
}
intent1.putExtra("math token", mathToken);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent1);
finish();
```